# German Volume Training 10 sets X 10 reps

Tags: weightlifting

I am curious as to what others experiences with this training program are. Did you gain the 5-12 lbs of muscle over the 6 week period that promoters such as Charles Poliquin claim to be the norm ? While I realize that the excessive volume is the driving force behind the hypertrophy gains, I am wondering whether a load that equates to 60% of one's 1 rep max will stimulate enough muscle fibres to lead to a significant amount of muscle growth. Looking forward to the responses.

Comment: 5-12 pounds of muscle in 6 weeks?  With or without anabolics?

Comment: Definitely without.

Comment: Count me as a disbeliever.

Comment: Give it a try and then answer your own question.

Answer (score -1):

If you are newbie with no training at all. You might see such results. Otherwise it is not going to work for sure.

Comment: I have been training for years. I have hit a plateau. So I am looking to switch things up a bit. I have heard good things about this program. I am just concerned the lack of intensity/load will not be enough to elicit hypertrophy.

Comment: Here is my humble suggestion. When you hit a plateau try getting time off for a week or even two. That helps shake it up.

Comment: To boost the intensity in HIIT100 my suggestion would be to add another 3 sets on top of the 10 where you go to failure and finally a drop set. I'm guessing the first 10 sets you will go with 50% of your 10RM. You can play with the pause periods between sets and the speed of reps (explosive or slow) Variation is king :) Hope this helps.